# Additional 1 bit UDR0 data displayed when reading BLE Data

Tags: c, embedded, uart

```
#define F_CPU 1000000
#define BAUD 9600
#define MYUBRR ((F_CPU/16/BAUD)-1)

#include <avr/io.h> 
#include <util/delay.h>

void USART_Init(unsigned int ubrr){
    UBRR0H = (unsigned char)(ubrr >> 8);
    UBRR0L = (unsigned char)(ubrr);
    UCSR0B |= (1 << TXEN0) | (1 << RXC0);
    UCSR0C |= (1<<USBS0)|(3<<UCSZ00);
}

void USART_Transmit(unsigned char data){
    while (!(UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)));
    UDR0 = data;
}

void USART_putstring(char * StringPtr){
    while (*StringPtr != 0x00){
        USART_Transmit(*StringPtr);
        StringPtr++;
    }
}

unsigned char USART_Receive( void )
{
     while (!(UCSR0A & (1<<RXC0)));
     return UDR0;
}

int main(void)
{   
    USART_Init(MYUBRR);
    char data[] = "1cm";
    while (1) 
    {
        USART_putstring(data);
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
    return 0
}
```

I am writing this program on ATMEGA328P using Atmel Studio and AVRDUDESS
When I set the data as 1cm I should get hex output as (0x) 31 63 6d however my output shows as (0x) B1 E3 ED it seems like additional 1 bit is added in every single byte.

Ex)

1 in ascii -> 0b110001(0x31) but I get as 0b1110001 (0xB1)

c in ascii -> 0b1100011 (0x63) but I get as 0b11100011 (0xE3) and so forth..

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Where are you *receiving* this serial data and what settings are in effect there?  You are not configuring the registers from scratch, but rather modifying what you assume to be defaults; what happens *before* this code runs?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am receiving this message from my android phone using nRF Connect App. I don't think anything happens after before running the code other than requesting data from the app

Comment: What I asked was what is connected to the *serial line* and what settings that is using to decode the serial word.  Those of course must match the settings you are using to generate the data.

Comment: See this question, it should help: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/61195/175629

Comment: I dont believe there is any decoding involved other than the code above inputting unsigned char as 'A' (or any other char) sorry I am new to this.

Comment: @linuxfan Thank you, so do you think i would have to change my UCSR0C initialization?

Comment: As pointed out by Chris, you should be shure about what UCSR0C contains, and what the settings in your receiver device are. The data sheet tells what is the default setting, but rewriting the entire register is safer and faster.

Comment: This system *cannot work* without something decoding the serial line and encoding BTLE packets.  Part of what you need to do is verify that the settings of *that* decoder (ie, the UART in the BTLE chip) match the settings of your ATmega UART.  Also beware in passing binary data through Java (ie on Android) of its handling of what it *thinks* are signed numbers; not clear you'd trip that with 8-bit data but if you start dealing with multibyte words it's easy to write code which corrupts certain values.

Comment: Check your settings on both transmitting device and receiving device.  It's almost as if the receiving device is clocking in a parity or stop bit from the transmitting device.

Based upon the header file `avr-libc/include/avr/iom328p.h`, it looks like the transmitter is setup to send 2 stop bits.  Also the data sheet recommends to set the baud rate before enabling the transmitter / receiver.  It would be a good idea to comment the code to state what mode you are trying to set up so people looking at it won't have to guess.